# how to close a webview which was opened by javascript in android programming

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have an android application which contains only one web view , I have loaded the url(which was developed by .net using javascript)in web view , It has facebook login , when user click on that facebook button,it opens the facebook dialog,if user don't want to login,he will click on go back on android but that facebook dialog still appears,how to go back fom facebook dialog to main web view?

I tried this code

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mainWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mainWebView.goBack();
                    Log.d("webview<---", "going_back");
                } else if (newWebView != null && newWebView.isFocusable()) {
                    FBWebView.removeAllViews();
                    FBWebView.clearHistory();
                    FBWebView.getParent();

                      FBWebView=null;
                    //FBWebView.addView(mWebView);
                    // FBWebView.loadUrl(url);
                    //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                    Log.d("fb_webview<---", "finish");

                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

still no use,Can Anyone suggest that how to go back from fb dialog to main web view ,here FBWebview is created dynamically in this  activity and mainWebview is intialised through xml , how to close fbWebView to appear the mainwebview?

Comment: Its not the webview it might be the Fb dialog that created the issue

Comment: ya  how to  close that fb dialog in android

Comment: check the fb developer sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below code in before return statement under `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` case:

```
  /* Closing newly created popup window */
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
                    newWebView.clearView();
                } else {
                    newWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                }
```